# "unresolved external..." when trying to build a class with CPP

Tags: c++

Today I downloaded the new version of visual studio, and I tried to build a class:

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction(int, int);


private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
};
```

I also built a cpp file for the implementation:

```
#pragma once
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <string>



Fraction::Fraction(int a, int b)
{ 
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
}
```

The header file (thc class) is in file called "Franctions.h" and found in the header files directory.
The cpp file (thc class) is in file called "Franctions.cpp" and found in the Resource files directory.

When Im trying to run this simple program, I get this issue:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fraction::Fraction(int,int)" (??0Fraction@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main    Homework2   c:\Users\VVV\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Homework2\Homework2\questionA.obj    1
```

Why can it be happening?

EDIT:
main:

```
#include "Fraction.h"

int main()
{
    Fraction f1(1, 2);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: CPP files belong in the source files, not resource files.  Move it to the source files folder and see what happens.  Also `#pragma once` should be in the header file, not source file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Still the same problem

Comment: `LNK2019` is the linker error, so probably something is wrong in your project's configuration. Where do you have file with `main()` function and other source files? Are they in the same directory as `Fractions.cpp`? It seems that from place where you use `Fraction` class only header file is visible.

Comment: Did you build also `Fracion.cpp`? Linked everything? It seems that you've compiled only main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not within your Fractions.h or Fractions.cpp, but rather with questionA.cpp note that the referencing file that cannot find the symbol in the error is:

```
c:\Users\VVV\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Homework2\Homework2\questionA.obj
```

Is `#include "Fractions.h"` in that file?

Comment: Sure... there is also declaration... :(

Comment: @efwef It seems that there is a problem with your solution. Can you take a screenshot of your "Solution Explorer" with stuff expanded where I can see Fractions.h, Fractions.cpp, and questionA.cpp?

Answer (score -2):

this error means that the compiler can't find this function.
write the specific place in the include path and see if it solve your problem.
if so, it means your header file is looking at different directory than the one you think.

Comment: This is wrong. An unresolved symbol indicates that the header or another satisfactory declaration is present, and the function is called correctly according to said declaration, but the source file or library containing the declared symbol is not linked in. If the header were missing, a completely different error would be printed, like '`Fraction` was not declared'.